# can't get the exact decimal percentage result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, casting, sql-server-2012

I create the following stored procedure to calculate the percentage ,it works fine but i always can't get the exact result

for example `98.000` instead of `98.947`

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_finger_calc_percent
AS
DECLARE  @no_action decimal(18,4);
DECLARE  @yes_action decimal(18,4);

 SELECT   @no_action = COUNT(*)
FROM         Action INNER JOIN
                      Employee ON Action.b_num = Employee.b_num INNER JOIN
                      Department ON Employee.dep_id = Department.dep_id
WHERE     (Department.dep_id = 50) AND (Action.action = 0);


SELECT   @yes_action= COUNT(*)
FROM       Action INNER JOIN
                      Employee ON Action.b_num = Employee.b_num INNER JOIN
                      Department ON Employee.dep_id = Department.dep_id
WHERE     (Department.dep_id = 50) AND (Action.action = 1);

If(@no_action = 0.00)
 return 100.00
Else return cast( (100.00  *(@yes_action  /@no_action ) )as decimal(18,4)) 
;

DECLARE  @return_status decimal(18,4);
EXEC @return_status = sp_finger_calc_percent
select @return_status;
```

Comment: It [looks like](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/1016) it should work fine.

Comment: Is the line `return cast( (100.00  *(@yes_action  /@no_action ) )as decimal(18,4))` correct, or should it be `return cast( (100.00  *(@yes_action  / (@no_action + @yes_action)) )as decimal(18,4))` ?

Comment: FYI you can do that in a single pass of the table `select @yes_action = SUM(Action.action), @no_action = SUM(case Action.action when 0 then 1 end) from ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Procedures in SQL Server can only return INTeger types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx)**. You need a real-valued Function to do this, I believe (or, better, as others have pointed out, a decimal OUTPUT parameter to your procedure).

Answer (score 1):

an other possibility would be using out parameters

```
Alter PROCEDURE sp_finger_calc_percent(@return_status decimal(18,4) out)
AS
DECLARE  @no_action decimal(18,4);
DECLARE  @yes_action decimal(18,4);

SELECT   @no_action = COUNT(*)
FROM         Action INNER JOIN
                      Employee ON Action.b_num = Employee.b_num INNER JOIN
                      Department ON Employee.dep_id = Department.dep_id
WHERE     (Department.dep_id = 50) AND (Action.action = 0);


SELECT   @yes_action= COUNT(*)
FROM       Action INNER JOIN
                      Employee ON Action.b_num = Employee.b_num INNER JOIN
                      Department ON Employee.dep_id = Department.dep_id
WHERE     (Department.dep_id = 50) AND (Action.action = 1);

If(@no_action = 0.00)
 select @return_status= 100.00
Else select @return_status = cast( (100.00  *(@yes_action  /@no_action ) )as decimal(18,4)) 
;
```

Call

```
DECLARE  @return_status decimal(18,4);
EXEC  sp_finger_calc_percent @return_status out
select @return_status;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to an output parameter (as mentioned by Alex K):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_finger_calc_percent
    @RETURNVALUE DECIMAL(18,4) OUTPUT
AS
...
If(@no_action = 0.00)
 SET @RETURNVALUE = 100.00
Else SET @RETURNVALUE = cast( (100.00  *(@yes_action  /@no_action ) )as decimal(18,4)) 
;
```